# Is it necessary to pass iterator by const reference

Tags: c++

```
class T
{
    unordered_map<string, int> table;
    ...

    void updateA(const unordered_map<string, int>::iterator& iter)
    {
        iter->second = 100; 
    }

    void updateB(unordered_map<string, int>::iterator iter)
    {
        iter->second = 100; 
    }
};
```

Question> Which function is better(i.e. updateA or updateB)? If you have a better one, please propose.

Thank you

Comment: If you are not going to change the value of the iterator it is definitely better to use the const one

Comment: I believe most, if not all, of the standard functions take iterators by value.

Comment: @chris yup looks like your right I'm guessing that is because iterators are never very large

Comment: @aaronman, I'm not too familiar with them on a low level, but I would imagine the only thing they are expected to be in any reasonable implementation is really just a pointer or an index.

Comment: @chris  I would guess that a smart compiler could probably optimize iters out of the code, in the end they are really just there to write better more readable code

Comment: @chris, not that aaronman is correct, in most cases, everything is optimized away; however, an iterator IS an index. Not a pointer to an index. Hence the problem of deleting an item in a map, vector, etc. and the iterator not "pointing" to the right place.

Comment: @AlexisWilke, I never said pointer to an index, I said pointer or index. Then again, I really don't know much about how they are implemented.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**1)** First, to answer the question in the title, is it *necessary* to pass iterators by (const) reference: No. An iterator acts as a proxy for the data item in the container, regardless of whether or not the iterator itself is a copy of or a reference to another iterator. Also in the case when the iterator gets invalidated by some operation performed on the container, whether you maintain it by copy or reference will not make a difference.

**2)** Second, which of the two options is better.

I'd pass the iterator by copy (i.e. your second option).

The rule of thumb is: Pass by reference if you either want to modify the original variable passed to the function, or if the object you pass is large and copying it involves a major effort.

Neither is the case here: Iterators are small, lightweight objects, and given that you suggested a const-reference, it is also clear that you don't want to make a modification to it that you want reflected in the variable passed to the function.

**3)** As a third option, I'd like you to consider adding `const` to your second option:

```
void updateC(const unordered_map<string,int>::iterator iter)
{
    iter->second = 100; 
}
```

This ensures you won't accidentally re-assign `iter` inside the function, but still allows you to modify the original container item referred to by `iter`. It also may give the compiler the opportunity for certain optimizations (although in a simple situation like the one in your question, these optimizations might be applied anway).

Comment: Out of curiosity:  Do you remember, what kind of optimizations you had in mind?

Comment: @MikeMB I think the optimization I had in mind was that the compiler would (a) inline the call to the function, and would (b) not have to allocate extra space for the copy of the iterator, since it is guaranteed not to be modified. So there wouldn't be any real function call, and no real copy either. (In simple situations, the compiler can be expected to recognize the opportunity for this anyway, even without `const` though.)

Comment: STL also has the CONTAINER::const_iterator. This may also need to considered.